# What procedure do i have to do

Tags: visa

My husband is an italian. What procedure should i do to be able to live also in italy with him. And also if ever, can I also bring with me my son which is not his biological son? Thank you so much.

Comment: What is your nationality / country of residence? How old is your son - is he dependent on you / your husband?